# Win from application gets slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, performance

I have built an application using Visual Studio .NET and it works fine. After the application is used for more than 2-3 hours it starts to get slow and I don't know why. I have used `GC.Collect();` to get memory leak problems but now I have the new one.
Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Without more details and/or code your question is probably too broad to answer. There are too many unknown factors; there probably won't be a simple and generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have a memory leak, just calling `GC.Collect()` will get you nowhere. The GarbageCollector can only collect those objects, that are not referenced from others anymore.

If you do not cleanup your objects properly, the GC will not collect anything.

When handling with memory consumptions, you should strongly consider the following patterns:

1. Weak Events ([MSDN Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx))
   If you do not **unsubscribe from events**, the subscribing objects will never be released into the Garbage Collection. `GC.Collect()` will **NOT** remove those objects and they will clutter your memory.
2. Implement the `IDisposable` interface ([MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx))
   (I strongly suggest to read this ducumentation as I have seen lots of wrong implementations.)
   You should always free resources that you used. Call `Dispose()` on **every object that offers** it!
3. The same applies to streams. Always call `Close()` on **every object** that offers this.
4. To make points 2. and 3. easier you can use the `using` blocks. ([MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx))
   As soon as these code blocks go out of scope they **automatically** call the appropriate `Dispose()` or `Close()` methods on the given object. This is the same, but more convinient, as using a `try... finally` combination.

Comment: is there any high difference with Debug and Release because i did a deploy in debug? is it faster when i build my setup in Release mode?

Comment: In general, applications in RELEASE mode will be slightly faster than the DEBUG mode because in DEBUG mode there is a lot of fancy stuff going on "behind the scenes" that will not run when deployed as RELEASE. But regarding the GarbageCollector this will not have much impact. I think this goes into the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try a memory profiler, such as the ANTS Memory Profiler. First you need to understand what's going on, then you can think about how to fix it.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/